# Convert nested class to dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, recursion, traversal

I want to convert a nested class to a nice key/value dictionary and keep the class names and nested paths for each property to make it easy searchable for later.

This is my example class:

```
var agreement = new Agreement
            {
                ID = 101,
                Description = "Convert to dictionary",
                Customer = new Customer
                {
                    FirstName = "John",
                    LastName = "Smith",
                    Age = 30,
                    Address = new List<Address>() 
                    { 
                        new Address 
                        {
                            Name = "Los Angeles 1",
                            ZipCode = 25437
                        }, 
                        new Address
                        {
                            Name = "New York 25",
                            ZipCode = 25441
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

And this is my expected key/value output in the dictionary:

```
KEY                                    VALUE
Agreement.ID:                          101
Agreement.Description:                 Convert to dictionary
Agreement.Customer.FirstName:          John
Agreement.Customer.LastName:           Smith
Agreement.Customer.Age:                30
Agreement.Customer.Address[0].Name:    Los Angeles 1
Agreement.Customer.Address[0].ZipCode: 25437
Agreement.Customer.Address[1].Name:    New York 25
Agreement.Customer.Address[1].ZipCode: 25441
```

Anyone has an idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: what type should KEY and VALUE have? object? string?

Comment: I am curious why you need to do this? It is for object dumping?

Comment: @TimPohlmann, The output dictionary is of type <key,value> = <string,string>.

Comment: @HarryQuake, yes it's for object dumping to a temporary dictionary before it gets exported to a file.

Comment: @Raskolnikoov please [edit] your question to contain your clarifications

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Apologies, I dont have time to test this.)

You could write a solution using reflection and recursion.  Something like this, below.

**You will want to add null checks, and other exit cases otherwise you will quickly end up in an infinate loop.**
This is just to get you started.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> MapToDictionary(object source, string name)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    MapToDictionaryInternal(dictionary, source, name);
    return dictionary;
}

private void MapToDictionaryInternal(
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, object source, string name)
{
    var properties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach(var p in properties) 
    {
        var key = name + "." + p.Name;
        object value = p.GetValue(source, null);
        Type valueType = value.GetType();

        if (valueType.IsPrimitive || valueType == typeof (String))
        {
            dictionary[key] = value.ToString();
        }
        else if (value is IEnumerable)
        {
            var i = 0;
            foreach (object o in (IEnumerable) value)
            {
                MapToDictionaryInternal(dictionary, o, key + "[" + i + "]");
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MapToDictionaryInternal(dictionary, value, key);
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary2 = MapToDictionary(agreement, "Agreement");
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank to Buh Buh, his solution works great.
Just adding some configurations and bypass loop deep.

// Defining methods

```
    public class ObjectConvertInfo
    {
        public object ConvertObject { set; get; }
        public IList<Type> IgnoreTypes { set; get; }
        public IList<string> IgnoreProperties { set; get; }
        public int MaxDeep { set; get; } = 3;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> ConvertObjectToDictionary(ObjectConvertInfo objectConvertInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            MapToDictionaryInternal(dictionary, objectConvertInfo, objectConvertInfo.ConvertObject.GetType().Name, 0);
            return dictionary;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void MapToDictionaryInternal(IDictionary<string, string> dictionary, ObjectConvertInfo objectConvertInfo, string name, int deep)
    {
        try
        {
            if (deep > objectConvertInfo.MaxDeep)
                return;

            var properties = objectConvertInfo.ConvertObject.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                if (objectConvertInfo.IgnoreProperties.ContainIgnoreCase(propertyInfo.Name))
                    continue;

                var key = name + "." + propertyInfo.Name;
                var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectConvertInfo.ConvertObject, null);
                if (value == null)
                    continue;

                var valueType = value.GetType();

                if (objectConvertInfo.IgnoreTypes.Contains(valueType))
                    continue;

                if (valueType.IsPrimitive || valueType == typeof(String))
                {
                    dictionary[key] = value.ToString();
                }
                else if (value is IEnumerable)
                {
                    var i = 0;
                    foreach (var data in (IEnumerable)value)
                    {
                        MapToDictionaryInternal(dictionary, new ObjectConvertInfo
                        {
                            ConvertObject = data,
                            IgnoreTypes = objectConvertInfo.IgnoreTypes,
                            IgnoreProperties = objectConvertInfo.IgnoreProperties, MaxDeep = objectConvertInfo.MaxDeep
                        }, key + "[" + i + "]", deep + 1);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MapToDictionaryInternal(dictionary, new ObjectConvertInfo
                    {
                        ConvertObject = value,
                        IgnoreTypes = objectConvertInfo.IgnoreTypes,
                        IgnoreProperties = objectConvertInfo.IgnoreProperties, MaxDeep = objectConvertInfo.MaxDeep
                    }, key, deep + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

// And call

```
var result = cryptoService.ConvertObjectToDictionary(new ObjectConvertInfo
                {
                    ConvertObject = objectToWrite,
                    IgnoreProperties = new List<string> { "PropertyA", "PropertyB"},
                    IgnoreTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(IntPtr), typeof(Delegate), typeof(Type) },
                    MaxDeep = 3
                });
```

**Update for missing method**

```
public static bool ContainIgnoreCase(this IEnumerable<string> list, string value)
    {
        if (list == null || !list.Any())
            return false;

        if (value == null)
            return false;

        return list.Any(item => item.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Buh Buh's solution is quite effective, but require a small adjustment.
I made a little change because it wasn't functioning when the Property Type was DateTime.

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> MapToDictionary(object source, string name)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        MapToDictionaryInternal(dictionary, source, name);
        return dictionary;
    }
    
    private void MapToDictionaryInternal(
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, object source, string name)
    {
        var properties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach(var p in properties) 
        {
            var key = name + "." + p.Name;
            if (value == null)
            {
                dictionary[key] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Type valueType = value.GetType();
                if (valueType.IsPrimitive || valueType == typeof(String) || valueType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    dictionary[key] = value.ToString();
                }
                else if (value is IEnumerable)
                {
                    var i = 0;
                    foreach (object o in (IEnumerable)value)
                    {
                        MapToDictionaryInternal(dictionary, o, key + "[" + i + "]");
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MapToDictionaryInternal(dictionary, value, key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```